# Where did I go wrong computing this trig integral?

Tags: integration

I don't know latex but I have my work written out in [image: this image]. The answer seems to be incorrect and I am aware of the trig substitution trick that is usually used to solve this integral. I'm not interested in memorizing such a substitution and I don't need the answer since I can look it up if I need to. I'm wondering where my work went wrong here, and how to fix it so that memorizing dubious substitutions won't be necessary.

I also attempted this integral by writing $\sin(x)$ in exponential form via eulers identity and ended up with $\ln(\left |\frac {e^{ix} +1}{e^{ix} -1} \right|) +C$ as my answer, but here I am stuck trying to convert this back into trig terms. I suspect this answer is incorrect as well, probably for the same reason my first answer is incorrect.

What are non-memorization based ways of solving this integral and why is my approach incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form of answers may vary in indefinite integration. We can always apply derivative to validate the result.

As $\cos2y=2\cos^2y-1=1-2\sin^2y,$

$$\left|\frac{\cos x-1}{\cos x+1}\right|=\left|\frac{-2\sin^2 \frac x2}{2\cos^ 2\frac x2}\right|=|-1|\tan^2\frac x2=\tan^2\frac x2$$

$$\text{So,} \ln\left|\frac{\cos x-1}{\cos x+1}\right|=\ln\left|\tan^2\frac x2\right|=2\ln \left|\tan\frac x2\right|$$

---

Alternatively, you can use [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution#First_example)

Comment: Thank you, that was a very clear explanation. I've never seen that last substitution before. It's very amazing, how does one come up with such a parameterization of the unit circle?

Comment: @RR, not sure if I understood your query correctly. If you mean $x^2+y^2=1$ we can parametrize with $\cos\theta,\sin\theta$

Comment: @RR, may also have a look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricSubstitution.html

Comment: I meant on the last section of the Wiesterstrass substitution article where it talks about how this change of variables captures (mostly) all of the points on the unit circle. Perhaps I just need more time to read through it.

Comment: @RR, use m=1 in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple

Comment: @RR: For parameter $t$, consider the line slope $t$ through $(-1,0)$. This meets the unit circle at the second point $(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\frac{2t}{1+t^2})$. that gives the desired parametrization, misses only $(-1,0)$, which roughly corresponds to $t=\infty$. The idea is **widely** useful.